# Google colab deletes my unzipped files after restarting session

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, tar

I am trying to extract (tar.gz) a 2.2GB dataset on my google drive that I need to run models on Colab.

I use the command `!tar -xf source.tar.gz -C destination` to extract it to my desired directory.

After 30 minutes, it is extracted and all the files are properly extracted.
I restart the session after a while and i see that I am missing more than half of the files. So I extract them again and I close my session, come back and see that almost all are missing.

How could I fix this? Also the google drive interface is very laggy and async from all the changes that are happening in the Colab.

I really need the GPU on colab. How do I resolve this issue?

I even tried using `tf.keras.utils.get_file` with the extract option on but I have lost most of my files again after i opened the notebook.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that it is shared with some other people with whom i am in the project with. Is it possible that there is not enough space and it stores them in memory while the session is running and is not able to fully move them to the drive?

Answer (score 4):

You have the option to map your Google Drive into your Colab virtual machine:

1. Click on *Files* at left.
2. Click on *Mount Drive*.
3. New folder with name *drive* appears, that points to your Google Drive.
4. Let's save all persisent files here.

[image]

Comment: Is there any performance issue if you use files from mounted Google Drive in compare to using uploaded files directly to Colab?

Comment: Yes, there usually is. For best performance, you will want to transfer the files directly into the virtual container of Colab.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is a **limitation** of Google Colab, based on [Google's Colaboratory FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#executed-code)

> Q: Where is my code executed? What happens to my execution state if I
> close the browser window?
>
> A: Code is executed in a virtual machine private to your account. Virtual
> machines are deleted when idle for a while, and have a maximum
> lifetime enforced by the Colab service.

The virtual machine that runs the code is recycled after a certain amount of inactivity. There's no mechanism yet to persist data saved on Colab right now.

### Possible workaround:

I have stumbled upon a video from `1littlecoder`'s YouTube channel that shows how to prevent [Google Colab Session Runtime from Closing with JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VkKlHuE4JQ).

The video is using `document.querySelector` that clicks a button every `setInterval` to avoid idle time.

**Disclaimer**: I am not affiliated with the video nor the YouTube channel.

### References:

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html

https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VkKlHuE4JQ

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector